# Google Scholar picks up right article but wrong pdf

Tags: google-scholar

My Google Scholar picked up the right article, as in, the title and abstract is correct, but the wrong pdf. How do I fix the link to the article?

Please suggest.

Thank you!

Comment: you may be out of luck: see https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/106764/correcting-the-authors-name-on-google-scholar; https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/117354/how-can-an-error-in-google-scholar-be-corrected; https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/105480/is-there-a-way-to-report-to-google-scholar-some-systematic-mistakes/105497#105497